# Methods for finding solution to $A\mathbf{x}=b$ problem

Tags: matrices

Let $A=PDP^{-1}$ where $P = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&2&1\\2&-5&-3\end{bmatrix}$ and $D=\begin{bmatrix}8&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&7\end{bmatrix}$.
Find all solutions to $x = \begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}$ to equations $A\mathbf{x} = 8 \mathbf{x}$.

I tried the brute force approach and calculated $P^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\-2&3&1\\4&-5&-2\end{bmatrix}$ so that we get $A=\begin{bmatrix}8&0&0\\28&-35&-14\\-68&105&42\end{bmatrix}$.

So we have 1 degree of freedom and we can set $x_1$ to have which ever value:

\begin{align*}
\begin{cases} 8x_1 &= 8 x_1 \\ 28 x_1 - 35 x_2 -14 x_3 &= 8 x_2\\
-68 x_1 + 105 x_2 + 42 x_3 &= 8 x_3 \end{cases}\\
\begin{cases}-43 x_2 &= 14 x_3 - 28 x_1\\
36 x_3 &= 68 x_1 - 105 x_2 \end{cases}\\
\begin{cases}x_2 &= - \frac{14}{43} x_3 + \frac{28}{43} x_1\\
x_3 &= \frac{68}{36} x_1 - \frac{105}{36} x_2 \end{cases}
\end{align*}
so $x_1$ and $x_2$ are...
\begin{align*}
x_2 &= -\frac{14}{43} \left( \frac{68}{36} x_1 - \frac{105}{36} x_2 \right) +\frac{28}{43} x_1 \\
x_2 &= \frac{14}{387} x_2 + \frac{28}{42} x_1 \\
\frac{373}{387} x_2 &= \frac{28}{42} x_1 \to x_2 = \frac{258}{373} x_1
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
x_3 &= \frac{68}{36} x_1 - \frac{105}{36} \left(\frac{258}{373} x_1 \right) \\
x_3 &= -\frac{863}{6714} x_1
\end{align*}

But I have been given hint that there is a easy (and sane..) way of solving this without finding $P^{-1}$ or $A$. I get that if $A= \lambda I$ it solves $A \mathbf{x}=\lambda \mathbf{x}$ but $A \neq I$ in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the eigendecomposition of a matrix than the answer of Alijah Ahamed is the right hint for you.

If you don't know such decomposition than note that:

$$
A\mathbf{x}=8\mathbf{x} \quad \iff \quad PDP^{-1}\mathbf{x}=8\mathbf{x} \quad \iff \quad D(P^{-1}\mathbf{x})=8(P^{-1}\mathbf{x})
$$
let $\mathbf{y}=P^{-1}\mathbf{x}$, you have
$$
D\mathbf{y}=8\mathbf{y} \quad \Rightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
8&0&0\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&7
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
y_1\\
y_2\\
y_3
\end{bmatrix}
= 8
\begin{bmatrix}
y_1\\
y_2\\
y_3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
that is:
$$
\begin {cases}
8y_1=8y_1\\
0=8y_2\\
7y_3=8y_3
\end{cases}
\Rightarrow
\begin {cases}
y_1=t \;\forall t \in \mathbb{R}\\
y_2=0\\
y_3=0
\end{cases}
$$
Now, since $\mathbf{y}=P^{-1}\mathbf{x} \Rightarrow \mathbf{x}=P\mathbf{y}$
we find:
$$
\mathbf{x}=\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&2&1\\
2&-5&-3
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
t\\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
t\\
0\\
2t
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
0\\
2
\end{bmatrix} t
$$
i.e. $\mathbf{x}$ is the space spanned by the first column of $P$, that is, in the language of eigendecomposition, the eigenspace of the eigenvalue $8$.

Comment: Thanks! Small typo in $x$ thought? Isn't third element 2 and not -2?

Comment: Yes! I edit the typo :)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: you are given the eigendecomposition of matrix $A$, as $A=PDP^{-1}$.

What will the columns of $P$ and the diagonal entries of $D$ correspond to?

Comment: So the diagonal elements of $D$ are the eigenvalues and the columns on $P$ are the corresponding eigenvectors. So the problem is basically $A\mathbf{v} = \lambda \mathbf{v}$ which results to $\mathbf{x}$ is the first column of $P$ i.e $\mathbf{x} = [1\;0\;2]^T$ ?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.